# The managed object is not valid - Dynamo Crashes

Tags: python, autodesk, revit

The following error in Dynamo is bugging me since many hours.

> **Warning**:
>
> IronPythonEvaluator.EvaluateIronPythonScript operation failed.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File " < string > ", line 33, in < module>
>
> Exception: The managed object is not valid.

[image]

I’m not sure why the error has occur would appreciate if someone share its solution with me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
import Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry

# Import Element wrapper extension methods
clr.AddReference("RevitNodes")
import Revit

clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)

# Import geometry conversion extension methods
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.GeometryConversion)

# Import DocumentManager and TransactionManager
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager

doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument
uiapp = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentUIApplication
app = uiapp.Application

# Import RevitAPI
clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *

import System
from System import Array
from System.Collections.Generic import *

import sys

pyt_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib'
sys.path.append(pyt_path)
```

The above are my standard imports while working with Dynamo/Revit API. It has been working for me for a while.

In all honesty I wish I had an "actual" answer why your script is not working. The only thing that is different than mine, is order in which you reference certain things. That should have no effect on their validity. It's Dynamo though, and it's very capricious.